# Show such finite sequence of random variables is exchangable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

Given random variables $X_1$,$X_2$,...,$X_n$ i.i.d, $Z$ is random variable which is independent of $X_1$,$X_2$,...,$X_n$, Let $Y_i = X_i + Z, i = 1,2,...,n$, are $Y_1, Y_2, ... , Y_n$ exchangable(I guess so)?If so, how to show it?If not, what about $Z$ is also iid with $X_1$,$X_2$,...,$X_n$?

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use characteristic functions. We have $Ee^{i\sum_j t_jY_j}=\prod_jEe^{it_jX_j} Ee^{i \sum_j t_jZ}$ which clearly doesn't change under  any permutation of $t_j$'s. It is not necessary to assume that $Z$ has the same distribution as $X_i$'s.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X,Z\colon (\Omega,\Sigma,\mathbb P)\to \mathbb R$ be two random variables and $X_1,\dots,X_n\stackrel{\rm i.i.d.}{\sim} X$ be i.i.d. random variables that are independent of $Z$. For $A\in\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$, let $A-z := \{a-z|a\in A\}$ denote the shift of the set $A$ by $z\in\mathbb R$.

It is easier to first think of $Z$ as being a discrete random variable. Then for $A_1,\dots,A_n\in\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$ we obtain (by the [law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability) and the independence of all random variables:
\begin{align*}
\mathbb P\big( Y_1\in A_1,\dots, Y_n\in A_n\big)
&=
\sum_z \mathbb P(Z=z)
\mathbb P\big( X_1\in A_1-z,\dots, X_n\in A_n-z\big)
\\
&=
\sum_z \mathbb P(Z=z)
\mathbb P\big( X\in (A_1-z)\big)\cdots \mathbb P\big( X\in (A_n-z)\big).
\end{align*}
Since $X_1,\dots,X_n$ are i.i.d., you obtain the same result for $\mathbb P\big( Y_{\sigma(1)}\in A_1,\dots, Y_{\sigma(n)}\in A_n\big)$, where $\sigma$ is some permutation of $\{1,\dots,n\}$.

If $Z$ is not discrete, we have to use integrals instead of sums:
\begin{align*}
\mathbb P\big( Y_1\in A_1,\dots, Y_n\in A_n\big)
&=
\int_\mathbb R 
\mathbb P\big( X_1\in A_1-z,\dots, X_n\in A_n-z\big)
\, \mathrm d\mathbb P_Z(z)
\\
&=
\int_\mathbb R 
\mathbb P\big( X\in (A_1-z)\big)\cdots \mathbb P\big( X\in (A_n-z)\big)
\, \mathrm d\mathbb P_Z(z),
\end{align*}
where $\mathbb P_Z$ is the distribution of $Z$.

*Remark*:

1. It is not necessary for $X$ and $Z$ to map into $\mathbb R$. It can be any space you like. In order to make your question well-posed, you have to be able to perform the addition $X+Z$, though, so probably they map into the same vector space $V$.
2. We used the fact that the product $\sigma$-algebra is generated by the sets of the form $A_1\times\cdots\times A_n$.